# A project migration to Codename One

Tags: android, migration, codenameone

I'm migrating android application to Codename One. I would like to cover the complexity of  different UI implementation of Android and iOS by Codename One framework.

The question is how to implement the logic behind? Lets say storage io, webservice call, crypthography, ws objects generated by Axis... well, all of these are packed in jars.

I assume the logic behind cannot be molten in Codename One translation capabilities to iOS or other platforms. But  **is there a way togenerate UI via Codename One, then [download source code](http://www.codenameone.com/pricing.html) (PRO package provides *Download generated sources from the server* option) for each platform and finally add 3th parties libraries?** Or is this type of migration totally not worth it? Is there other framework, which provide better abstraction of cross platform UI and behind logic?

PS: Actually I did not find the way how to get the generated source code download from build server. Did it anybody?

Thank you,
Milan Baran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the built source just right click the project select project properties and select the include sources checkbox (you will need to login with a paid account first for this to work). FYI if you are a pro account you can also just email a question and get a faster answer.

You can use the native interfaces regardless to access these things in Android, but as you say this won't work for iOS.

Most of these are already abstracted to some degree, Codename One has Storage, Database & FileSystem API's. Cryptography isn't included but there is a [bouncy castle port](http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/06/bouncy-castle-crypto-api.html) (notice the cn1lib which solves the problems of jar's with native code). Codename One has builtin JSON, XML and CSV parsers. However, at this time it doesn't have anything equivalent in scope to Axis. One of the problems of these tools (e.g. JAXB) is the reliance on reflection/bytecode manipulation neither of which make much sense in a native app (would force the inclusion of the entire JVM and limit optimizations).